# jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9 dependency issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I was trying to add jacoco maven plugin in my pom.xml file but getting below error while building the project.

```
 Execution default-prepare-agent of goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9:prepare-agent failed: Plugin org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.7.9 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2, 
    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2: Could not transfer artifact commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2 from/to central (https://artifactory.corp.chartercom.com/plugins-release): 
     Access denied to https://artifactory.corp.chartercom.com/plugins-release/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.2/commons-codec-1.2.jar. Error code 403, Forbidden
```

I have tried a couple of things as mentioned below:

1. I have tried to upgrate jacoco version for 0.7.9 to 0.8.4, 0.8.5 and 0.8.6 and try to exclude `commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2` and `commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2` jar form jacoco plugin but it doesn't work.
2. I have also tried to add upgraded dependencies of commons-codec and commons-collections jars in my pom.xml but it doesn't work.

here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.charter.ews.location</groupId>
<artifactId>search-address-api</artifactId>
<version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>search-address-api</name>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <charter.logging>1.2</charter.logging>
    <charter.error>1.1</charter.error>
    <charter.transactionalizer>1.2</charter.transactionalizer>
    <swagger.version>2.7.0</swagger.version>
    <charter.algorithm.lib>1.0.0.RELEASE</charter.algorithm.lib>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Charter dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.charter.web.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>transactionalizer</artifactId>
        <version>${charter.transactionalizer}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.charter.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>charter-logging</artifactId>
        <version>${charter.logging}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.charter.error</groupId>
        <artifactId>charter-error</artifactId>
        <version>${charter.error}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- junit -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/model/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/config/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/exception/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/constants/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/Application.class</exclude>
                </excludes>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin> <!-- Copy configuration files to a location accessible by Helm. Use mvn resources:copy-resources 
                for execution -->
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>chart/files</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>config</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                    <include>**/*.yaml</include>
                                    <include>**/logback*.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <filtering>false</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin> <!-- Helper to 1) change SNAPSHOT to RELEASE. 2) Frame Docker image name -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <name>newVersion</name>
                <value>${project.version}</value>
                <regex>-SNAPSHOT|-build\.(.*)|-build</regex>
                <replacement>-build.${BUILD_NUMBER}</replacement>
                <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                <source />
                <fileSet />
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is this error has anything to do with setting.xml file ? your suggestions will be highly appriciated.

Comment: can you please show the settings.xml file...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of commons-collections4, You can try adding commons-collections dependency as shown below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or you can directly give commons-collections dependency  in jacoco plugin as shown below.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.7</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/model/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/config/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/exception/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/constants/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/com/charter/address/Application.class</exclude>
                </excludes>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```